# asp.net core 3 server websocket support

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asp.net-core, iis, websocket

I have a REST server for my game in asp.net core 3 MVC ...

The client is Unity3D.

I want to have some websockets stuff for a part of this server.

I've made websocket server before. I had a console app as a server and I was using [websocket-sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp) library for both client (unity3d) and server.

I tried to implement websocket sharp on my new server, but is seems that this library doesnt work on iis...

I have problems adding websocket to this new server.

The first result everyone will face after searching for this issue, is [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr). It doesn't have a unity3d client. (Actually, there is a [non-official](https://unitylist.com/p/a5h/Signal-R-Client-Unity-Net-46) port, but as the  author says: it's not extensively tested)

There is [pure websocket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.0) too. But I can't connect to the server at all. I'm using [browser websocket client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/browser-websocket-client/mdmlhchldhfnfnkfmljgeinlffmdgkjo?hl=en) to test my server.

Also I've found some people [who](https://radu-matei.com/blog/aspnet-core-websockets-middleware/) [wrote](https://peterdaugaardrasmussen.com/2019/01/20/how-to-use-websockets-with-asp-net-core-with-an-example/) [some](https://github.com/Elfocrash/PewChat/tree/master/PewChat) middleware stuff.

Non of them worked for me even after cloning their repos.

The only one that was kinda semi-worked, was [this one](https://github.com/radu-matei/websocket-manager/tree/master/samples/MvcSample).

Why "semi-worked"?

I can connect to the server after cloning his rep ( mvc sample ). I even changed the target to dotnetcore 3 and everything was alright.

But when I copy-paste his classes to another project targeting dotnetcore 3 ( and I did EnableEndpointRouting=false stuff), the client can't connect to the server...

Can anyone help me with this?

Am I missing any configuration things?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions to activate WebSocket in IIS? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.0#enabling-websockets-on-iis)

Comment: @S.Fragkos yeah...

Answer (score 1):

Use Kestrel instead of IIS.

If you really want to author a C# server, you should familiarize yourself with how to start a server completely programmatically.

You can view a working two player networked example of SignalR server and client running in the Unity client [here](https://github.com/doctorpangloss/Multiplayer/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/HiddenSwitch/Networking/Peers/Internal/SignalRServer.cs). You do not need to modify any source to make AspNetCore SignalR work in Unity. This runs great on my macOS editor.

Use the built-in C# websocket server classes otherwise.